# Sitecore 9 Page Test in "Experience Optimization"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Sitecore Experience Optimization Page Testing.

I am trying to test created simple page in Experience Optimization. Locally everything working fine. When i tried same steps in Azure environment it giving me errors like below.

HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.
(XHR)POST - https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/api/sitecore/Settings/SetUserProfileKey

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/shell/api/ct/ItemInfo/GetByUri?datauri=sitecore%3A%2F%2F%7BED7C2C82-114C-4FB1-96A7-6CCF1F37317B%7D%3Fver%3D2%26lang%3Den&_=1518266879976

HTTP500: SERVER ERROR - The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
(XHR)GET - https://mc-4b5a2ea8-f571-4c60-bf02-50220a-cm.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/shell/api/ct/ItemInfo/GetByUri?datauri=sitecore%3A%2F%2F%7BED7C2C82-114C-4FB1-96A7-6CCF1F37317B%7D%3Fver%3D2%26lang%3Den&_=1518266879972

Please check attached screenshots for same.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update for All viewers.

Thanks to @Pete Navarra for answer.

This is a stretch... But I think you are hitting the URL max length, with the length of your domain name. Can you shorten your machine names?

I will try and keep you update on same.